# How to run a Windows GUI which needs OpenGL 1.2+ with Microsoft Basic Display Adapter?

Tags: windows, windows-7, graphics-card, display-driver, opengl

I'm facing the problem that some my test systems are not able to handle [GUI applications which use the OpenGL 1.2 or higher display their GU](https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne)I.

These problematic test systems all show a "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" in the device manager. **The hardware vendor does not provide any GFX drivers** and told me that the standard Microsoft GFX drivers have to be used.

If I read out the OpenGL capabilities via [GLVIEW](https://www.realtech-vr.com/home/glview) it shows OpenGL version 1.1. but at least 1.2+ is needed for the GUI framework.

I found an [OpenGL® Compatibility Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/opencl-and-opengl-compatibility-pack/9nqpsl29bfff?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) which seems to be exactly what I need but the system requirements for this pack are Windows 10 version 19041.488 and I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 10.0.14393 and are not allowed to update because of the Long Term Servicing Branch I'm enforced to use. Additionally I need to run this on some older Windows 7 systems.

Is there any way to run an OpenGL application under Windows for older systems with this Basic Display Adapter Driver?

Answer (score 1):

You can use software OpenGL implementation from Mesa.

Windows binaries are available on website [Mesa3D for Windows](https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag). No changes to application are required, since whole implementation is inside single file **opengl32.dll**.

I personally used it successfully for:

1. Running my own visualizer faster over RDP. It used OpenGL 1.1 + extensions.
2. Running Qt-based GUI of big CAD software (requires at least OpenGL 2) inside VirtualBox VM where it did not run natively.